# How to flag comments with constructive as well as non-constructive content?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

[Heat Detector](https://stackapps.com/questions/7001/heat-detector-analysing-comments-to-find-heat) digs up some comments now and then that contain constructive things as well as non-constructive remarks. For example:

> It would be better to swap X and Y and call method Z then. And @otheruser please leave, you're not helping anyone.

Usually those remarks aren't really rude (a rude flag wouldn't qualify), but I think they shouldn't be there.

So, should I ignore the comments or flag them as non-constructive, which would cause a loss of potentially valuable information if it gets deleted?

Comment: It's non-constructive to ask someone else to stop being non-constructive? /boggle

Comment: @canon: Yes, it just starts fights. Best to flag and move on! (I'm bad at remembering to do this)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Flag as "Other" and explain the situation to the mods.

Mods can then choose to edit the comment or delete the comment. Mods *can* edit comments, and this seems like the perfect use of that ability.

If the mod feels it's better to delete the comment out right, there shouldn't be a problem with you reiterating the constructive part of the comment in another of your own, or an answer if appropriate.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware moderators could edit comments... that sounds like the best approach here indeed!

Comment: I knew team members could, but had to [look it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284422/switch-edit-pencil-direction-for-comments-edited-by-other-than-attributed-author) to verify that mods could. I don't think they use that ability often, but it can be handy. :)

Comment: Yes, This is the best option. A related read on a [similar topic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281766/311398).

Comment: @BhargavRao the linked answer makes it look like comments only get edited if the constructive part is *really* important. If it's just average stuff, it gets deleted anyway?

Comment: @Floern, It depends on the comment, but usually if the comment is worth saving, then we try to keep it. This occurs in very rare cases as usually the comments are never both constructive and non constructive. If you other flag such a comment, then the chances of it being edited are more, than if you flag it using the standard reasons.

Comment: @Floern - It also depends on how the comment is structured. We don't like to do anything that might appear to be putting words in someone's mouth, like rewording a comment. However, if we can simply delete a sentence from a comment to remove the non-constructive portion, I'm far more likely to edit in that case.

Comment: @BradLarson I'm glad that that's the policy over here, since I've been [quite upset](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/q/3130/47336) elsewhere on Stack Exchange by a moderator editing my comments in a way that (to my sensibilities) converted a strongly-worded but professional comment into one that was pointlessly nasty and aggressive towards another user. People's different ideas of what is or isn't rude make this area a minefield, and putting words into people's mouths is indeed something to avoid at all costs.